# how to navigate a specified tab to new url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension and on start, I open a new tab. This will be my "work" tab.

How to navigate to a new url in this tab?
How to identify this tab and tell him to navigate to the new url?

I'm trying with this code:

```
chrome.tabs.query( { active: true, currentWindow: true }, function( tabs ) {
    chrome.tabs.update( tabs[0].id, { url: "http://stackoverflow.com//" } );
  });
```

but this navigates the current tab to the new url. I need to navigate in my "work" tab.

I think I will need to take an id from the tab that I created on start and use this id as a destination for the later navigates.
but, how to do this?

Comment: you can use something like `chrome.tabs.create({index: 0, url: 'http://stackoverflow.com'}, function() {});`

Comment: perfect. now i can control where to open the tab. how to navigate in this tab to another url? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

fixed.

when create the tab, use:

```
chrome.tabs.create({index: 0, url: 'http://stackoverflow.com'}, function() {});
```

for update the url in this tab:

```
chrome.tabs.query( { active: false, currentWindow: true }, function( tabs ) {
    chrome.tabs.update( tabs[0].id, { url: "http://stackoverflow.com//" } );
  });
```

active must be set to false.